# jQuery/JS plugin to create website introduction / showcase for new users

Tags: javascript, jquery, highlighting

I want to create website introduction for new customers.

Is there any plugin/framework that highlights certain areas of website and shows text for those areas? I've seen about year ago such plugin with demo but couldn't find it.

I prefer stand-alone or based on jQuery one.

thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I bookmarked this a long time ago just in case I ever needed something like it...

http://tympanus.net/Development/WebsiteTour/

Comment: I've seen much more advanced one but unlike you i forgot to bookmark... thanks anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Here is another

http://www.zurb.com/playground/jquery-joyride-feature-tour-plugin

Answer (score 1):

This page prived a large set of available plugins:

http://www.jquery4u.com/plugins/web-tour-instructional-plugins/

Answer (score 0):

Bootstro (http://clu3.github.io/bootstro.js/#) is awesome introduction Plugin we are using. Very intuitive and minimal setup required.

Answer (score 0):

All the other answers require a dependency like Bootstrap and Foundation. The Typmanus demo is pretty basic and will work but leaves much to be desired. However after researching I had to come back to offer up my favorite solution https://usablica.github.io/intro.js/